# ¿Cómo puedo enviar una imagen docker a otro ordenador sin usar el docker hub?

Tags: docker, ssh

Quiero transferir una imagen docker con sus datos de un Windows 10 a un Fedora 35 utilisando ssh [como lo muestre Donald Kinghorn](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Use-SSH-Client-and-Server-on-Windows-10-1470/) pero cuando cargo la imagen que creía haber descargado no tiene los datos que había en la imagen en Windows.

Sobre Fedora hice:

```
ssh me@windowsaddress


Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1415]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

me@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V C:\Users\me> docker save neo4j | ssh -C me@fedoraaddress docker load 

me@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V C:\Users\me>docker images
REPOSITORY                    TAG         IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE  
neo4j                         latest      59f06d5b803f   2 months ago    575MB 
my-app                        1.0         e42e200cfd8d   4 months ago    125MB 
data-tools_etl                latest      73306695e8a2   5 months ago    607MB 
mongo-express                 latest      dc564d602ca5   5 months ago    136MB 
mongo                         latest      269b735e72cb   5 months ago    682MB 
mysql                         5.7         09361feeb475   6 months ago    447MB 
metabase/metabase             latest      79b9026b1454   7 months ago    408MB 
alpine/git                    latest      b8f176fa3f0d   7 months ago    25.1MB
deeplearningai/mlepc1w1-ugl   jupyternb   bbb4b3565c40   10 months ago   2.31GB
```

Pero los datos que veo no son los datos que hay en el docker de Windows.

Aqui estan las imagenes sobre Fedora:

```
bash-5.1$ docker images
REPOSITORY     TAG                     IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
serious-game   0.0.1                   92d06326c49d   3 weeks ago    1.77GB
serious-game   latest                  92d06326c49d   3 weeks ago    1.77GB
seriousgame    latest                  92d06326c49d   3 weeks ago    1.77GB
neo4j          <none>                  120e18f5415d   4 weeks ago    579MB
fedora         latest                  b78af7a83692   6 weeks ago    153MB
ubuntu         latest                  ba6acccedd29   2 months ago   72.8MB
neo4j          latest                  59f06d5b803f   2 months ago   575MB
hello-world    latest                  feb5d9fea6a5   3 months ago   13.3kB
nvidia/cuda    10.2-base-ubuntu18.04   84b82c2f5736   3 months ago   107MB
```

Comment: La ip que muestras es interna de docker, no es la ip pública de la máquina

Comment: La interfaz que debes mirar es la enp3s0, o la wlp5s0, que no tienen IP en el momento que muestras. Problemas con dhcp en el arranque, probablemente.

Comment: También puedes usar `docker image export` y eso te creará un archivo .tar.gz que puedes subir a algún lugar de internet, para bajarlo de allí desde la otra máquina y añadirlo a docker con `docker image import`. Esto te evitará problemas si las máquinas no se pueden comunicar directamente por estar detrás de un router nat, o un cortafuegos, o algo de esto.